# Instructables DIY current limiter circuit

Tags: mosfet, batteries, voltage-regulator, constant-current, bias

I found [this](https://www.instructables.com/World-simpliest-DC-current-limiter/?amp_page=true) inline and was hoping if that circuit is okay. Instead of a battery though, I want to use a dynamo (plenty of juice-wise).
Output of dynamo is 18 V 200 mA. I wish I could adjust the current to how I want it: 20 mA, 40 mA etc. using a pot. Is it possible? Also, will the voltage be affected?

Comment: *if that circuit is okay.* Impossible to say (It looks quite questionable! You don't need to use a circuit that uses a second power source just to regulate a current). What do you want to *do* with it? Whether something is fit for a purpose depends on the purpose. I ask because, while you say that you want limit the current, you also ask a very strange question: "will the voltage be affected?" Obviously, yes, it will, I mean, you limit a current, so the voltage *must* be affected; that's really basic physics.

Comment: Have you tried to simulate the circuit?

Comment: also, general strategy remark: The author of said circuit says "I'm an amateur". That means his / her circuits are not as good (at least in expectation) as circuits designed by someone who actually learned what they're doing. The internet is full of actual electronics advice by actual electrical engineers. Do not stick to low-quality sources of information when you can have high-quality sources.

Comment: **imran**, dynamos are complicated devices and were I looking to get the most out of one I'd probably be looking for a double-conversion circuit with the first part of it tailored to optimize the load that the dynamo sees and the second part designed to deliver your current source. WIthout any details about what you are doing, not much can be added. You may want to [look here](https://www.mikrocontroller.net/attachment/14850/BikeLight.pdf) for some thoughts, though.

Comment: But for the most part, a dynamo outputs DC power supply,  correct?

Comment: @imranmuhd usually, a dynamo (a bike dynamo anyway) delivers AC

Comment: @Andyaka: Not a duplicate -- completely different circuit, although the form of the question is the same.

Comment: And the un-addressed comments in that earlier question are also still valid here too. It's a duplicate.

Answer (score 2):

As the circuit shows, a FET, supplied with a constant VGS, is a reasonably current source, for reasonable values of 'reasonable'.

Several caveats.

- VGSth is thermally sensitive. The current will drift as the temperature of the FET changes
- It's only a reasonable current source. The current will change a little as the output voltage changes.
- Make sure you have enough heat-sinking on the FET for the power it has to dissipate
- The circuit shows a 9 V battery and 1 k pot for supplying the VGS. As the battery runs down, so will the VGS and so will the FET current. You'll need to keep adjusting it.
- The circuit shows a 9 V battery and 1 k pot for supplying the VGS. The comment is made that this takes 7 mA, and it's implied that this is not too much. It's way more than is required. A FET takes essentially zero gate current, and so a 1 Meg pot would be quite adequate. This also means the battery would last longer, and the battery voltage would change less over time.